# AzureDataFactory: Downloading a Excel file from URL with HTTP Connector gives The excel format '' is not supported issue

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, httpconnection

I'm trying to copy an Excel file from an URL to my Azure Blob Storage. For the same purpose, I have a HTTP Linking Service that has the base url. I'm using this Linking Service in the DataSet (Excel file Format) for the Copy Activity. The URL is publicly accessible and I'm not using any authentication.

*URL*: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962

*Sheet name*: **Sheet1**

I always get

> The excel format '' is not supported while only supporting '.xls' and
> '.xlsx'

But the file is in xlsx format. Any help will be much appreciated . Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this:

1.Source dataset format: select Binary format.

2.Setting of Http link service
Base URL:https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=521962,
Authentication type select Anonymous.

3.Sink dataset format:select Binary format.And file path like below image:
[image]

4.download the `Financial Sample.xlsx` and you can see the data.

Hope this can help you.